# Google account to use for releasing company app on the Android Market

Tags: android

I will be releasing two applications soon, one for my company and one for me. Publishing app on my own is straightforward, but I'm not sure which account to use for the company.

What practice do you use in your company?

I only see one solution, creating a special google account like android@company.com shared by the company Android devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the single shared account for the android devs is the best way.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the only sensible solution.